# How to merge two pdf file using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, fpdf, mpdf

My pdf files are stored in the database.I wants to merge this all pdf file  and result is single pdf file.Im using mpdf library.

Comment: Pls check out the following guidance on improving your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question As it currently stands, it is unlikely that you will get an answer.

Comment: You can use FPDI to concatenate PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

mPDF is not the best tool to merge PDF files.

Alternative,approach that you can use is generate invoices from both the files into one file.

For Example:

```
$invoice_nos = ['0' => 'ISE-00000014Y18', '1' => 'ISE-00000005Y18'];
$mpdf = new \mPDF('utf-8', 'A4', '', '', 5, 5, 36, 10, 5, 4);
 //iterate through each invoice 
 foreach ($invoice_nos as $key => $invoice_no) {
    $html = 'Invoice No - ' . $invoice_no;
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak>');
}

$pdf_file_name = $invoice_no . 'invoices.pdf';
$mpdf->Output($pdf_file_name, 'f');
```